# ngx-indexed-db Getting error message. How to resolve?

Tags: indexeddb

I am new to indexedDb. The concepts of "in-line" and "out-of-line" keys are still fuzzy to me. I am trying to load the indexedDb with data that already has an 'id' value, so I don't want indexedDb to assign one.

I am getting this error:

ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore':
The object store uses in-line keys and the key parameter was provided

Here are the relevant code excerpts. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import { ObjectStoreMeta, ObjectStoreSchema } from 'ngx-indexed-db';
import { IrsFormInfo } from '../models/irs-form-info';

const STORE_NAME = 'irsfips';

const STORE_SCHEMA: ObjectStoreSchema[] = [];

export const STORE_CONFIG = {

    keyPath: 'id',

    autoIncrement: false,

};

export const STORE_META: ObjectStoreMeta = {

    store: STORE_NAME,

    storeConfig: STORE_CONFIG,

    storeSchema: STORE_SCHEMA

};

public createStore() {

    this.dbService.createObjectStore( STORE_META );

}

public addIrsFormInfo(
    fip: IrsFormInfo
) {

    console.log( 'addIrsFormInfo ', JSON.stringify( fip, null, 4 ) );

    this.dbService
        .add( this.STORE_NAME, fip, fip.id )
        .subscribe(
            ( key ) => {

                console.log( 'addIrsFormInfo key: ', key );

            }
        );

}
```

Comment: when calling add/put, do not specify the second parameter, just specify the first parameter